# Python program times-out when hitting this website

Tags: python, python-requests, get, urllib

Why does this function fail to read XML from "https://www.seattletimes.com/feed/"?

I can visit the URL from my browser *just fine*. It also reads XML from other websites *without a problem* ("https://news.ycombinator.com/rss").

```py
import urllib


def get_url(u):
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=header)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    return response.read().decode('utf-8')

url = 'https://www.seattletimes.com/feed/'

feed = get_url(url)

print(feed)
```

The program times out every time.

**Ideas?:**

- Maybe `header` need more info (`Accept`, etc.)?

**EDIT1:**

I replaced with the request `header` from the script with my browser header. Still no-go.

```
header = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure why but the `header`/`user-agent` was confusing the website. If you remove it your code works just fine. I've tried different header arguments without issues, the `user-agent` seems to be what causes that behaviour.

```py
import urllib.request


def get_url(u):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url=url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    return response.read().decode('utf-8')

url = 'https://www.seattletimes.com/feed/'

feed = get_url(url)

print(feed)
```

---

After some debugging I have found a legal header combination (keep in mind I consider this a bug on their end):

```
  header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=kfdkdofsdj99g36l443862qeq2',
        'Accept-Language': "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",}
```

Comment: Interesting. For some of the sites I hit, a `'User-Agent'` header *is* required. Do you how to programmatic check whether a site requires a `'User-Agent'` (using `urllib` or other means)?

Comment: I do not think you can really determine if some sites requires some header field or not. To be honest I would just launch the request with a `user-agent` set and if this does not yield a result launch another request without it.  I consider this a bug. Sites should not suddenly stop working when one does specify the `user-agent`.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I visited this site (`http://myhttpheader.com/`) and created the `header` variable accordingly (see **EDIT 1** above). Still no-go. What is the diff between the Python script running the call vs. my browser?

Comment: I have found a legal combination but as I said were are petty much debugging their site at this point :D